# Gradle Eclipse: 'Referenced Libraries' vs 'Project and External Dependencies'

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'm using Eclipse IDE for a Java Gradle project. I have a number of dependencies listed in Gradle, both from Maven Central and some local jars as files.
Using `gradle 4.5.1`, `Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)`

Calling `gradle eclipse` gives me the following view in Eclipse:

[image]

As you can see there is both a `Project and External Dependencies` and a `Referenced Libraries` section. There are a lot of the same jars in there, but the `Project and External Dependencies` seem to contain mismatched or outdated versions.

Should I have only one section? How should these different configurations be used?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. Install Gradle plugin for Eclipse
2. Import Gradle project to Eclipse
3. `Right click in your project` -> `Gradle` -> `Refresh Gradle Project`

Comment: This helped, but I have to do it very often (almost after every save). Is there a more stable way to work in a java gradle setting using eclipse?

Comment: I am using Eclipse Buildship Plug-in. From what I know about this plugin, it is not support auto refresh gradle project when gradle file is changed.